# Matching parts of string using regex grouping constructs

Tags: c#, regex, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I have the following string format:

```
CC-SS[PC|PC|...|PC]
```

where:

- CC is country code
- SS is state code
- PC|PC|...|PC is pipe delimited string of postal codes

The right parts of the string may not exists. For example:

- US
- US-IL

are valid strings.

So, I want to use a regex to get only particular details of the strings (if such exists).

I have try using named-groups and some variations of the pattern below:

```
^(?<country>.*)(?<=-)(?<state>.*)(?<=\[)(?<postalcodes>.*)(?=])
```

The above pattern has two issues:

- first, it is working only for the full representation of the string (the shorten ones are not matched)
- second, I was not able to deny the match of the delimiters (`-`, `[`, `]`)

Usually, I am using positive or negative look-ahead/behind and match everything except the delimiter - `[^.\]]` but I am not sure how to apply this technique when multiple groups are matched.

Could anyone advice something I can try?

Comment: Personally I think, though powerful, regex is not always the best option as it results in hard to read and debug code.  I would be fairly straightforward to parse the above string with a custom function.

Comment: @TimRutter Thanks. That's how I am doing this now. Just wondering if I can make it shorter/smarter using regex.

Comment: General advice: don't use `.*` and a look-ahead, match the characters up to a delimiter by using a negative character class. For example, to match everything up to the first `-` just match `[^-]+`

Comment: `\b(?<country>[A-Z]{2})(?:-(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?\b(?:\[(?<postalcodes>[^][]*]))?`? See  [this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3ccountry%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3a-%28%3f%3cstate%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%29%3f%5cb%28%3f%3a%5c%5b%28%3f%3cpostalcodes%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%5d%29%29%3f&i=CC-SS%5bPC%7cPC%7cPA%5d%0d%0aUS%0d%0aUS-IL)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It seems to work. I will test more now.

Comment: Just the last `]` should be outside the `postalcodes` group, I fixed it in the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you may use

```
\b(?<country>[A-Z]{2})(?:-(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?\b(?:\[(?<postalcodes>[^][]*)])?
```

In C#:

```
var rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<country>[A-Z]{2})(?:-(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?\b(?:\[(?<postalcodes>[^][]*)])?");
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%3f%3ccountry%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%28%3f%3a-%28%3f%3cstate%3e%5bA-Z%5d%7b2%7d%29%29%3f%5cb%28%3f%3a%5c%5b%28%3f%3cpostalcodes%3e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d*%29%5d%29%3f&i=CC-SS%5bPC%7cPC%7cPA%5d%0d%0aUS%0d%0aUS-IL).

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<country>[A-Z]{2})` - Group "country": two uppercase ASCII letters
- `(?:-(?<state>[A-Z]{2}))?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `-` - a hyphen
  - `(?<state>[A-Z]{2})` - Group "state":  two uppercase ASCII letters
- `\b`  - a word boundary
- `(?:\[(?<postalcodes>[^][]*)])?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `\[(?<postalcodes>[^][]*)` - Group "postalcodes": 0 or more chars other than `]` and `[`
  - `]` - a `]` char.

Comment: Thanks. I did not know that I can use `?:` combined with `capturing` sub-group.

Comment: @gotqn Groups and even lookarounds can be nested.